# Geometric series proof?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do I show that this given series is geometric:

$$(1/2) + (1/2)^4 + (1/2)^7 + (1/2)^{10} + \cdots$$

and therefore calculate the sum to infinity

Comment: First of all, you need to find out what the "..." means. Since there is no fully defined semantics of that symbol, the series might in fact go on like $$ (1/2)+(1/2)^4+(1/2)^7+(1/2)^{10}+(1/2)^{13}+(1/2)^{16}+(1/2)^{19}+(1/2)^{22}+(1/2)^{25}+(1/2)^{28}+(1/2)^{31}+\ldots$$ (see [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A016777)), which is *not* geometric. We simply cannot tell.

Comment: Why is this not geometric?

Comment: @Crookz : value of a convergent geometric series is $\frac{\mbox{first term in series}}{1-r}$, where $r$ is the common ratio.  Using this means you don't have to fuss with whether the first index is $n=0$ or $n=1$, what "$a$" is, etc.

Answer (score 4):

The first step in any series problem is finding an expression for the $n^\textrm{th}$ term.  Without this, you can't apply any of the tests.  In this problem, it looks like you're multiplying each term by $(1/2)^3$ to get to the next.  Hence, $a_n=a_0(1/2)^{3n}$, (and $a_0=1/2$).  Simplify this to get to the starting point of @lab's hint.  [note: he starts with $n=1$, and I start with $n=0$]

If you wanted to start with $n=1$, then $a_n=a_1(1/2)^{3(n-1)}$, and $a_1=(1/2)$.

Answer (score 1):

we know $\sum_0 x^n=\frac{1}{1-x} if |x| \le 1$ so

$(1/2) + (1/2)^4 + (1/2)^7 + (1/2)^{10} + \cdots =\frac{1}{2}\sum_0((\frac{1}{2})^3)^n=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{1-(\frac{1}{2})^3})$